# How to show that $\frac{n!}{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}$ diverges as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, radicals, factorial

The exact question is, is it true or not that

$$
n! = O(n^{\frac{n}{2}})
$$

I tried a few values of $n$ and guessed that it does not (this is obviously not very proper mathematics).

I applied the definition, i.e. I want to show that there does not exist an $N$ such that for all $n > N$ it is the case that

$$
n! \leqq c \cdot n^{\frac{n}{2}}
$$

I had two ideas as to how to proceed,

1. carry out a proof by contradiction (i.e. assuming that this $N$ does exist, but I wasn't able to derive an absurdity). I tried something along the lines of

Assume there exists an $N$ and a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n > N$ it is the case that
$$
n! \leqq c\cdot n^{\frac{n}{2}}
$$

Then it is also the case that because

$$
n! \geqq \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} \leqq n! \leqq c \cdot n^{\frac{n}{2}}
$$

But this does not help, because $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ just tends to 0.

I thought that I could try to use a bigger lower bound, i.e. something in the form $(an)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ where $a > 1$, but I'm not sure how to prove this exists.

2. try to pair up items on the left and right-hand sides and show that each item on the left-hand side (e.g. for showing that $n! = O(n^n)$ as there are the same number of terms on the left and right hand side it is possible to cancel them out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Sorry, as in after separating out $(1/2)^{n/2}$ then as this tends to zero there does exist a $c$ which works. (edit: now updated in post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried a few values of $n$ and guessed that it does not (this is obviously not very proper mathematics).

This is completely proper mathematics! Of course if you want to get a handle on what's going on you should look at specific values of $n$. Many posters on math.SE would be able to answer their own questions if they did this.

Anyway, this can be done using the following simple version of Stirling's approximation, which I learned from [Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula/). Starting from the identity $e^x = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, it follows that for $x \ge 0$ we have $e^x \ge \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for all non-negative integers $n$, hence that

$$n! \ge \frac{x^n}{e^x}$$

for all real $x \ge 0$. To get as good a bound using this as possible we want to choose $x$ such that the RHS is as large as possible. We can figure out what value of $x$ this is by taking the logarithm, then the derivative, then setting this equal to zero; the logarithm is $n \log x - x$ and its derivative is $\frac{n}{x} - 1$, so we get $x = n$, and hence the best possible bound we can get using this inequality is

$$\boxed{ n! \ge \frac{n^n}{e^n} }.$$

Now it's easy to see that $\frac{n!}{n^{\frac{n}{2}}} \ge \frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{e^n}$ goes to infinity, since for example once $n \ge 9$ we have $n^{\frac{n}{2}} \ge 9^{\frac{n}{2}} = 3^n$.

This is probably the simplest nontrivial example of a [saddle point bound](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/the-man-who-knew-partition-asymptotics/); the more general saddle point bound has many applications to figuring out the asymptotics of sequences more complicated than the factorials.

Comment: Wow! I know of the Taylor series for $\exp(x)$, but I'd never considered that it could be used to connect the two like that. Thank you so much! (Also, do you know of any good introductory resources on saddle point bounds?)

Comment: @peritremic: you can look at Chapter VIII of Flajolet and Sedgewick's *Analytic Combinatorics*: http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Stirling (see wikipedia) would help you but that's no fun.

Try to pair terms together $n!$ to form products that are all larger than $n$. Then you just need one pair to be of order larger than $n$ for the whole thing to be of order larger than $n^{n/2}$.

Edit : did not see that you already suggested that in your question. It works. Spoilers under the line

---

Basically you can show that

$n \times 1 \geq n$,

$(n-1)\times 2 \geq n$

and so on,
moreover the central product $n/2 \times (n/2+1) \geq n^2/4$.

You can then deduce $\dfrac{n!}{n^{n/2}} \geq n/4$.

Comment: $n/2 \times (n/2+1) \geq n^2/4$

Comment: indeed, thank you @Gary.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$a_n=\frac{n!}{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$
Is a positive sequence and has a factorial in it, we usually use the ratio test.
we  find that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\right)$$
$$=(n+1)\left(\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\right)$$
$$=(n+1)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$$
$$=(n+1)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

and given that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=e^{-1}$$
we get that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to +\infty} (n+1)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to +\infty} (n+1)^\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}=+\infty$$

Hence, and according to the ration test, the series is divergent  which forces the sequence itself to be divergent.

Comment: Thanks, this is very neat!

Comment: @peritremic, you’re more than welcome 

Answer (score 0):

No need to Stirling's approximation formula. By a property of Gamma function,

$$n!=\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx>\int_n^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx>\int_n^{\infty}n^ne^{-x}dx>n^ne^{-n},$$ therefore $\frac{n!}{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}=\frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{e^n}\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: What is $\Gamma$?

Comment: Function that extends the factorial function...

Comment: Nobody can memorize Starling's formula.

Comment: How does it extend the factorial function? To non-integer values?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't matter to this argument anyway since the identity $n! = \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} \, dx$ is only needed for non-negative integer $n$ and it has an elementary proof by induction using integration by parts. Bob did not need to mention the Gamma function at all, it just makes this argument seem more complicated than it is.

Comment: @BobDobbs It is Stirling and not Starling. I could memorise it in the form $$
n! \sim \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12n}} + \frac{1}{{288n^2 }} - \frac{{139}}{{51840n^3 }}} \right)
$$ and in many other forms when I was $15$. It is possible.

Comment: @Gary Wow. I hope you know it at 51 too.